# Spawn an Activity on top of anything else in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-intent, android-activity

I am looking for ways to spawn an Activity on top of any other opened Activity (of my app or of other apps).

Empirically, I found that opening a new Activity by using the startActivity API with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag, places the newly opened Activity on top of every other Activity.

Interestingly, this only happens if the startActivity API is called from a Service. If it is called from an Activity, the newly generated Activity will not go on top of Activities of other apps.

More precisely, if you run the following code from a Service:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Spawned.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The Activity  *Spawned* will be drawn on top of any existing Activity (even of a *different* app). Calling the same code from an Activity will not show it on top of other apps' Activities.

Do you have any explanation for this behavior?

Do you know if there are other ways to spawn an Activity on top of every other?

The official documentation is not clear about this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link where you have read this "this only happens if the startActivity API is called from a Service"?

Comment: I do not have a link, but I tested it. See the code I added by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) it's quite clear:

```
When the current activity starts another, the new activity is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus.
```